# Big query Pivoting with a specific requirement

Tags: google-bigquery, pivot-table, looker

I have used pivot in big query, but here is a specific use case and the data that I need to show in looker. I am trying the similar option in looker but wanted to know if I can just show this in big query.

This is how my data (Sample) in `BIG QUERY` table is:

[image: Sample data for table "BIG_QUERY"]

The output should be as below:

[image: Sample Output]

If you look at it, it's pivoting but I need to assign the column names as shown (for the specific range) and for the range 6 and more, I need to add the pivot columns data into one.

I don't see pivot index or something like this in `BIG_QUERY`. Was thinking if there is a way to sum up the column data after pivot index 6 or so?  Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: see [How to create a column that shows if a date appears in the last 7 days in BQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72649778/5221944) - it is conceptually exactly what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope below approach would be helpful,

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT Node, bucket, total_code 
    FROM sample, UNNEST([RANGE_BUCKET(data1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])]) bucket
) PIVOT (SUM(total_code) `range` FOR bucket IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7));
```

output:

[image]

- **RANGE_BUCKET** - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#range_bucket